# Rule of thumb or guidelines for custom flooring transition strip width?

Tags: threshold

I have installed 3/8" floating laminate in the living room, and in the kitchen we have tile. The laminate is 9/16" lower than the kitchen tile. I'm going to make a threshold similar to this:

[image]

Is there a rule of thumb of how deep I should make this (dimension A) for a 9/16" rise, and dimension B, of how much over the tile (dim B) it should be?

I will be making this out of solid oak.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There really isn't. I'd consider an appropriate slope to be somewhere between 22½° and 45° from horizontal. Take into consideration the style of nearby moldings.

Practically speaking, the total height of the thing above the lower floor surface is what matters. It's a trip hazard regardless of slope, and therefore *height* should be minimized. Just keep in mind that the wider you make it the more visually conspicuous it is, and the more fragile it is. At some point it becomes a hassle to step over.

Regarding lap, it just needs to be enough to support the strip so it doesn't crack when the piano rolls over it, and covers completely even if the flooring shifts a little seasonally.

I just recently did a transition very similar to this. Instead of lapping the tile, I reduced the transition height by making the strip flush on top (level with the tile). I then used a color-matched silicone caulk to create a durable, flexible grout joint between the tile and the wood. It came out beautiful and there's virtually no trip hazard.

```
_____________________ __ ________________
      tile           |__|           ______\___________________
                      ^ |__________||           laminate
                 grout joint  transition
                                strip
```

I'd consider doing that instead of adding height with a lap. It does require that you have a clean tile edge. I actually recut my tile edge with an angle grinder first so it was clean and straight. I also masked both sides of the grout joint before applying caulk so I could tool it into a cove without squooging caulk onto the strip and flooring.

Comment: I like the idea of not needing a lap, and I do have a clean tile edge, as well as color match caulk. It would certainly simplify the build.

Comment: This is a very good suggestion as it minimizes the height of your transition. And if you want a really good looking line on the tile side, you could use a Schluter strip where the grout joint is show in the ascii drawing.

Comment: The tile is already down.

Comment: I made the strip so it will be flush. Will get before/after pictures when done. Would you suggest nailing it down or gluing it (liquid nails??). The flooring is 3/8" floating laminate.

Comment: I'd bed it in adhesive and use nails only where necessary to snug it down to the laminate.